# Compare items in different dictionaries with same key using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two dictionaries with a string key and different value types.

```
private Dictionary<string, IProperty> _properties;
private Dictionary<string, Expectation> _expectations;
```

I need to compare elements sharing same key and get matching Expectations. Here's my method signature in Expectation class.

```
public bool Matches(IProperty property)
```

How can I do that using LINQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var result = _expectations.Where(e => _properties.Any(p => p.Key == e.Key && e.Value.Matches(p.Value)));
```

Comment: It really feels counter intuitive to do a linear search to find the correct key in `_properties` when it is a dictionary. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35543859/533837) for a simple alternative.

Answer (score 5):

If i get you correctly,

You can inner join both of the collection and than get value back

```
var exp = form p in _properties
          join e in _expectations
          on p.key equals e.key
          select e;
```

for detail youcan check this image :
[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = from pKey in _properties.Keys
             where _expectations.ContainsKey(pKey)
             let e = _expectations[pKey]
             select e;
```

It's more efficient than a join, because it takes advantage of the key lookup in `_expectations`. It could be slightly improved by using an extension method like that:

```
public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
    where TValue : class
{
    TValue value;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        return value;
    return null;
}

var result = from pKey in _properties.Keys
             let e = _expectations.GetValueOrDefault(pKey)
             where e != null
             select e;
```

(it avoids looking up the key twice)

Answer (score 1):

```
var matches = _expectations.Where(
    kvp => _properties.ContainsKey(kvp.Key) && kvp.Value.Matches(_properties[kvp.Key]));
```

If you know that the key exists in both dictionaries you can remove the `ContainsKey` check as well:

```
var matches = _expectations.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Matches(_properties[kvp.Key]));
```

---

The result from the above will be KeyValuePairs. To get directly at the Expectations simply append `.Select(kvp => kvp.Value)` to the above method of choice.